# Android 4.4.2 - Youtube webview plays only the sound of the video

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm writing an application and in an activity there is a webview with a youtube video or channel.
It worked well until I upgraded my phone to Android 4.4.2 KitKat. Now it plays only the sound of the video.
This is my webview:

```
 WebView web_video = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_video);
 WebSettings webSettings = web_video.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 web_video.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
 web_video.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
          super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
          if(newProgress==100){
               loading.dismiss();
          }
      }
 });
 web_video.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RC0ayg9Jj9I");
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Ensure you marked your activity or window as hardware accelerated

Answer (score 0):

Please check the notes in the google developer page for the changed WebView behaviour. 
I suspect the custom URL Handling is causing your problem.

The WebView implementation changed in 4.4 from WebKit base to Chrome base.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs